# Usage of automatic allocation with variable size (alloca) unexplained in literature

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm reading *Fundamentals of Embedded Software - Where C and Assembly Meet (2001)*, and was presented the following code:

```
FILE *OpenFile(char *name, char *ext, char *mode)
{
    int size = strlen(name) + strlen(ext) + 2;
    char *filespec = (char *) alloca(size);
    sprintf(filespec, "%s.%s", name, ext);
    return fopen(filespec, mode);
}
```

The author does not clarify why alloca is useful, or what it achieves. He claims *"most common reason to allocate dynamic memory from the heap is for objects whose size is not known until execution time..."*

However, I don't see why he couldn't just write `char *filespec = (char *) size;` at line 4.

Comment: ``alloca`` is used to allocate space on stack (move stack pointer) dynamically. Since you do not know name and ext size at compile time, you should allocate it dynamically (at runtime). It could be done in heap (malloc and friends) or stack (alloca). Or use VLA in C99 as all other commenters wrote)

Comment: char *filespec = (char *) size; at line 4 would just cast the size variable into a pointer with very bad results when you tried to dereference it.  I.e. if size is 30, then filespec would be a pointer to the memory location at 30.

Comment: @user996142 I think I understand now. alloca(size) creates space on the stack (and keeps track on where it starts and ends) so that I can temporarily store an array there. Did I get that right?

Comment: @B.Lee yes. Stack variables have  *automatic* storage duration because they are automatically removed when you exit the function. You do not need to free them (as you may need with heap-based data). They are faster also, but stack is not so big as heap and always cleared when function returns

Comment: @user996142 to be pedantic, the stack is always invalid after the function returns.  I doubt it's ever actually cleared.

Comment: `alloca` is not a standard C function. You better use a VLA instead. And do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends (including `alloca` if it is available).

Comment: The C standard does not even talk about a stack. That is an implementation detail you should not even think about.

Comment: @Olaf I get the impression that VLA is a very important tool. However, I recently read that VLA is optional in C11. Not sure if I'm going off topic; but what is another good alternative approach?

Comment: @B.Lee: It is (and I use it myself in my embedded projects, e.g. for TLS). Making it optional was one of the worst decissions in C11 imo. You should definitvely do more research on how C implementations work and the C [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). You would not have asked for other alternatives if you had already (no offence). Just use VLAs. It is very unlikely a compiler which supports C99 will not provide the same features in C11 mode.

Comment: @Olaf No offense taken. I've been writing in C# and Java for three years, just jumped into C. It's quite a different experience.

Comment: Well it is. I jump between Python (desktop) and C (embedded), but have decades of background. However, the good thing is you have much less to fight with complex framework libraries **by default** (that might change dramatically with some - possibly very expensive, yet bugged - proprietary libraries the customers forces you to use).

Comment: @RussSchultz  is absolutelly right. ANSI C does not give any guarantees about it. It may be cleared. May be not. No one should depend on stack content after function return (just like on heap content when data free()d). Pointer to such area is called *dangling* pointer or pointer-to-nowhere.

Comment: 'most common reason to allocate dynamic memory from the heap is for objects whose size is not known until execution time..' - I doubt that is remotely true.  What about all those classes where the number of instances needed is unknown?  What about all those instances where the lifetime must be extended?  I wonder if the author has ever written any non-trivial software at all?

Comment: @MartinJames CV of Daniel W. Lewis makes him look credential. If you have any tips for better books on Embedded design feel free to write them. Mind that this book is from 2001 though, maybe I'm doing myself a disfavor reading it. https://www.scu.edu/engineering/cse/dlewis/upload/Resume-13-March-2015.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `alloca` in your programs these days please :-)
It's not the same as (char *) size! It's the same as `char filespec[size]`, but he'll have used it because VLA's (variable-length arrays) were probably not available in his compiler (they came in C99 and you should use them) in addition to probably not having access to the heap in the embedded application.

Comment: Just to clarify: C99 supports dynamic-sized arrays, so one do not need alloca in this case since dynamic-sized could be used?

Comment: @dune.rocks I was curious about VSA's; the author had actually used VSA in the same example further down. However, he mentions alloca is useful when you have several returns in a function. Do you disagree with this? (Maybe I should get a updated book)

Comment: I don't like the term `dynamic-sized` here because people will immediately think of the heap. They're called variable-length arrays, and if you have access to a recent-ish tool-chain, you can use them instead of alloca

Comment: I do disagree with that, what difference do you think the number of returns make's here?

Comment: @dune.rocks Well, I was thinking compared to malloc where you should call free() when you leave the function (if you want to release the memory at function return), you'd be at a better place to use alloc which automatically freed the memory. Not sure how this works with VSA's though.

Comment: VLA's are also removed on a scope-exit (e.g., a function return) because they exist on the stack. It's the compiler will allocate that variable amount of stack space for you (incidentally using alloca's under the hood)

Comment: @dune.rocks: For gcc at least, there is a difference between a VLA and `alloca`: The latter will persist until the enclosing function is left. So you could pass a pointer to it from an inner scope. Just to mention, as legacy code might rely on this strange behaviour); I fully agree that VLAs are the way to go and they are not **dynamic** in the sense of resizeability.

Comment: VLA size could be computed in runtime, that is why I called it dynamic, but I understand now it is bad name. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

[alloca](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca) allocates on the stack, which means it will be deallocated after function ends, no manual free required. [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) allocates on the heap and requires manual release. These two functions are fundamentally different. (You did not ask about malloc but I presume you might be.)

Also explicit casting that you describe does not do any allocation either, it just makes a cast that does not make any sense as far as I can tell. That casting would not make code correct.

Comment: Note: C does not support methods, only functions! And `alloca` is not part of the standard.